Strange artifacts on model
I started modelling recently and the model I am working on has some rendering artifacts. I modelled the thing through extrusion and ended up with some distorted section, even if the faces are square and there are no duplicated vertices.
Here's the view from the top:

And from the bottom:

I need help in understanding the root cause and how to fix the issue.
Thanks

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

I would go to the Object Data (Green Triangle) tab of the Properties panel on the right, go to Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data and see if that helps first off.

Sadly it didn't work

It was solved by recalculating Face Normals in Edit Mode with Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Inside or shortcut Ctrl+Shift+N.
